# Monotonicity of $y(x)=1+xy(x)^m$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, monotone-functions

I want to know the monotonicity of this function $y(x)$ defined by
$$y(x)=1+xy(x)^m,\quad x\in[-\frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^m},\frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^m}]$$
A power expansion of $y(x)$ is $$y(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{mn}{n}\frac{x^n}{(m-1)n+1},\quad y(0)=1,$$
where $m>1$ is a positive integer.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete answer:

Consider the inverse:

$$y^{-1}=\frac{x-1}{x^m}=x^{1-m}-x^{-m}$$

The derivative is given by $(1-m)x^{-m}+mx^{-1-m}$, which is equal to $0$ when

$$(m-1)x^{-m}=mx^{-1-m}$$

$$x=\frac m{m-1}$$

Plugging this back in, we get

$$y^{-1}=\frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m-1}}-\frac{(m-1)^m}{m^m}$$

There is also the additional point $x=0$, where the derivative of the inverse becomes undefined and approaches $\pm\infty$ as $x\to0$, depending on the parity of $m$. Since it approaches infinity, we can ignore this case.

And so you have a monotone function over any interval not containing $\frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m-1}}-\frac{(m-1)^m}{m^m}$, assuming $y$ uniquely exists. It is clear from the series expansion that this is increasing on $\left[0,\frac{(m-1)^m}{m^m}\right]$, and thus increasing on $\left[\frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m-1}}-\frac{(m-1)^m}{m^m},\frac{(m-1)^m}{m^m}\right]$, but whether or not this is increasing near $-\frac{(m-1)^m}{m^m}$ I am unsure.

Comment: Where does the value $\frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m-1}}-\frac{(m-1)^m}{m^m}$ come from? – In my calculation, the function $x = x(y) = \frac{y-1}{y^m}$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \frac{m}{m-1}]$, so that the inverse function $y = y(x)$ exists (and is strictly increasing) on $(-\infty, \frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m}}]$.

Comment: From plugging $m/(m-1)$ into the inverse @MartinR

Comment: Actually $\frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m-1}}-\frac{(m-1)^m}{m^m} = \frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m}}$, so  I got the same value as you did.

Comment: So what is your doubt? The inverse function exists on $(-\infty, \frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m}}]$ and that is more than OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$
 f: \begin{cases} (0,\frac{m}{m-1}] &\to \Bbb R, \\
y &\mapsto \frac{y-1}{y^m} \,.
\end{cases}
$$
On the open interval $(0,\frac{m}{m-1})$ we have
$$
 f'(y)= \frac{m-(m-1)y}{y^{m+1}} > 0
$$
so that $f$ is strictly increasing. Also
$$
 \lim_{y \to 0} f(y) = -\infty \,, \quad f(\frac{m}{m-1}) = \frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m}} \, .
$$
It follows that $f$ is a bijective (increasing) mapping from $(0,\frac{m}{m-1}]$ to $(-\infty, \frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m}}]$. The inverse function $g = f^{-1}$ is defined on $(-\infty, \frac{(m-1)^{m-1}}{m^{m}}]$ and satisfies 
$$
 f(g(x)) = x \implies g(x) = 1 + x g(x)^m
$$
on that interval. As the inverse function of a (strictly) increasing function, $g$ is strictly increasing as well.